# Press Enter to Continue

Tags: c++, string, newline, cin

This doesn't work:

```
string temp;
cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
cin >> temp;
```

Comment: The right way to achieve this is: `inline void WaitEnter() { std::cout << "Press Enter to continue..."; while (std::cin.get()!='\n'); }` Most of the answers here is just messing about. You can even put this in a lambda if you want.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
cin.ignore();
```

or, better:

```
#include <limits>
cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

Comment: That is indeed a cross platform way, one can put << flush behind the cout and cin.sync() between those lines to make sure it works in every case. ;-)

Comment: cin is tied to cout, thus before any i/o of cin happens, the output of cout is flushed already

Comment: @dani I think he argues that it is better because it the second version explicitly looks for a newline character, as requested.

Comment: What is the difference, isn't `cin.ignore()` also looking for a newline character? After a quick test here, I could not see any difference in behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
char temp;
cin.get(temp);
```

or, better yet:

```
char temp = 'x';
while (temp != '\n')
    cin.get(temp);
```

I think the string input will wait until you enter real characters, not just a newline.

Answer (score 8):

Replace your `cin >> temp` with:

```
temp = cin.get();
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/

`cin >>` will wait for the EndOfFile. By default, cin will have the *[skipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/ws/)* flag set, which means it 'skips over' any whitespace before it is extracted and put into your string.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
getchar();
```

On success, the character read is returned (promoted to an `int` value, `int getchar ( void );`), which can be used in a test block  (`while`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You need to include conio.h so try this, it's easy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {

  //some code like
  cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
  getch();

  return 0;
}
```

With that you don't need a string or an int for this just `getch();`

Comment: This answer isnt working anymore, the getch() function was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The function [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (already introduced with C++98) provides a portable way to implement this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void press_any_key()
{
    std::cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
    std::string temp;
    std::getline(std::cin, temp);
}
```

I found this thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33686108/2932052) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33686134/2932052) after I observed that `std::cin >> temp;` does not return with empty input. So I was wondering how to deal with optional user input (which makes sense for a string variable can of course be empty).

Comment: This is the only one that eats spurious input in the case where the line is not blank.  If used in a loop, the other answers will run multiple iterations in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, but for C. Requires Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Press any key to continue...");
    system("/bin/stty raw"); //No Enter
    getchar();
    system("/bin/stty cooked"); //Yes Enter
    return 0;
}
```