# how to read an empty string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

consider this code snippet in c++ -

```
string str;
cin>>str;
```

If I simply press enter at this stage, the pointer moves to next line but keep waiting for the input even if I intentionally want to input an empty string.

My objective is to read a word. And If I press enter, it should be taken as a empty string.

Comment: Don't use cin because it doesn't read a string - it reads a word.  Use getline to read a string.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah this behaviour can be changed with [std::noskipws](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) as stated in [mnciitbhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687470/2932052) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::getline`:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

Comment: I have included bits/stdc++.h

Comment: Its working. The actual problem was that I was reading an integer before reading the string. using cin.ignore solved the problem.

Comment: @VishalSharma The actual problem is the mere use of `operator>>`. Don't mix calls to `operator>>` and `getline()`. Actually, just stop using `operator>>` already – it's quirky, it's clumsy, it's hard to use correctly. If you want to read an integer, just use `getline()` and parse the input string using `std::stoi()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways :

Use `std::getline()`

```
std::string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

Or using `std::noskipws`

```
std::string str;
cin >> noskipws >> str;
```

Don't forget to use `cin.ignore()`.