# Not waiting for std::cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, iostream

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903230/6717178), I've written the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter x and y size, followed by enter: ";
    std::size_t nrOfRows, nrOfCols;
    std::cin >> nrOfRows >> nrOfCols;

    // initialize dynamic array of arrays
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> data(nrOfRows,
        std::vector<char>(nrOfCols, 'O'));

    // print array
    for (std::size_t rowNr = 0; rowNr < nrOfRows; rowNr++)
    {
        std::cout << "Row " << rowNr << ": ";
        for (const auto& el : data[rowNr])
            std::cout << el << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue: ";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Compiled with VC++ 14.1 or Visual studio 2017 v15.7.4.
After the first prompt I enter e.g. "3 5" and enter. Then the program just rolls through and exits. E.g. it outputs the strings and **does not wait for the final user input (enter) at `std::cin.ignore()`.**

What did I miss?

## edit

For the down-voters/nay sayers. This code does work as described.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue: ";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: @RetiredNinja As far as I know `ignore()` does pause the program. The problem is the line break left in there by the extraction operator.

Comment: Guess you're right, if there's nothing in the buffer it blocks. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the extraction operation (`std::cin >> nrOfRows >> nrOfCols;`) will leave delimiting whitespace in the stream, unlike `getline()`, which will consume the delimiter. This normally isn't a problem because the `>>` operator will also ignore leading whitespace, but the line break left in the stream will cause `std::istream::ignore()` to not wait for input.

To fix this, add a call to `std::istream::ignore()` to discard any whitespace before you output the `Press enter to continue:` message.